# Add translation programmatically in module installer

Tags: magento-1.8, inline-translations

I've created module and I want to add translations to `core_translate` database table. I created array with original string and translation in form:

```
$words = array(
  'MyCustomModule::StringToTranslate' => 'String translation'
   ...
);
```

and in install PHP file I tried with:

```
foreach ($words as $source => $translate) {
    $model = Mage::getModel('core/translate');
    $model->setString($source);
    $model->setTranslate($translate);
    $model->setLocale('pl_PL');
    $model->save();
}
```

and with:

```
foreach ($words as $source => $translate) {
    $model = Mage::getModel('core/translate');
    $model->setData('string', $source);
    $model->setData('translate', $translate);
    $model->setData('locale', 'pl_PL');
    $model->save();
}
```

but I still get an error. As I see in Mage/Core/Model/Translate it just a simple class.

How can I add my translations into that table?

Comment: Which error do you have?

Comment: I had no method found exceptions for setData() and others setTranslate(), setString().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no save() function implemented in translate model and it does not extend from Mage_Core_Model_Abstract so you can not use the model for persisting data. instead you need to use resource model directly like this:

```
    /* @var $resource Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Translate_String */
    $resource = Mage::getResourceModel('core/translate_string');
    foreach ($words as $source => $translate) {
        $resource->saveTranslate($source, $translate, 'pl_PL', $storeId);
    }
```

note that $storeId can be either null or int